# Do I really need a NoSQL Database?

Tags: database, nosql

**Background:** Trying to integrate two separate systems; Oracle and MS-SQL Server. Multiple applications reside on each and need to do ad hoc analysis.

**The Problem:** The reason I am considering a multiple NoSQL situation is the best course of actions is; There is a very complex and hierarchical relationship between some entities (military unit hierarchy). Such as each Unit has a complex relationship to Commands, States, Geographic location, and Mission. The user database is not special in this case, it as typical as any (No special social network graphing needed) But, I feel the Unit hierarchy would most benefit from a Graph Database when analysis is done.

The Second NoSQL consideration is that the current system cannot do any ad hoc analysis on the systems. As in, "brings it to it's knees" - Lead Developer had said to me once, writing custom scripts for top brass trying to do some sort of analysis with the applications.

So I was considering a Column/Big Table or Document database NoSQL solutions. This would be to create a "Data Lake" to house all the applications data and do some analysis.

**Solution:**

- What I am looking for is simply am I right to even consider this?
- Am I way off base for the idea?
- Am I missing some implementation that already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this question may be more appropriate for the DBA forum.  However the complex hierarchical question may be well-suited for developers.  Integrating two SQL databases is not a reason to use a NoSQL database.  SQL Server, and presumably Oracle, have ways of dealing with XML files.  XML files are good for complex hierarchical databases.  Well modeled data in SQL tables can accommodate the complexity.  NoSQL solutions can use JSON.  This is somewhat antithetical to hierarchical data.  JSON files are key-value pairs.

To answer your question, I don't see the nexus between integrating different SQL databases and using a NoSQL solution. NoSQL is good for large files (e.g., image files) associated with some other value.  I see no reason to use a NoSQL solution for your problem.

For analysis, can you take a snapshot of the database or create more indexes on the tables?  Then you could do the reports on the snapshots or indexes themselves?  There are other ways to offload reporting (e.g., through replication).  You may need more hardware.

You may want to use a data warehouse (a large database to send the data to). This could do the analysis.  OLAP cubes can have pre-aggregated data (Kimball cubes) for substantial analysis.  This way you don't lock up the OLTP databases with read locks.  If the data warehouse is on a separate server, it can be the target of exports from the regular databases.  This server can do the reporting processing.